# how to insert checkbox value without using array in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to insert the checkbox values into database, when I click the  particular checkbox corresponding value has to be inserted but for me previously checked checkbox values also again inserted into db how can I overcome this?
if I checked checkbox 1, inserted to database again I checked checkbox 2, my table shows checkbox1, checkbox1 ,checkbox2.
here I used foreach loop its the problem or any other method is there to get this problem.

JS Code :

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
  var ids = [];
  var dis = [];
  $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
    ids.push($(this).val());
  });
  $('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').each(function() {
    dis.push($(this).val());
  });
  dis = dis.toString();
  ids = ids.toString();
  $.ajax({
    url: "bodcheckbox.php",
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    data: ({
      value: ids,
      unchecked: dis,
    }),
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      alert("activitysubmitted");
    }
  });
});
```

PHP code :

```
session_start();
include 'config.php';
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
//if(isset($_POST['value']))
//{
//unchecked box value--
$unchecked       = $_POST['unchecked'];
$uncheckboxvalue = array();
$uncheckboxvalue = explode(",", $unchecked);
//--checkedbox value--
$checkbox    = array();
$checklist   = $_POST['value'];
$checkbox    = explode(",", $checklist);
$currentdate = date('d-m-Y');
$year        = date('Y', strtotime($currentdate));
$month       = date('F', strtotime($currentdate));
$date        = date('d', strtotime($currentdate));
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$currenttime = date("h-i-sa");
if (!empty($checklist)) {
    foreach ($checkbox as $check) {
        $bod_insert = mysql_query("insert into bod(username,activityname,tickeddate,tickedtime,status)values('$username','" . mysql_real_escape_string($check) . "','$date-$month-$year','$currenttime','yes')", $conn);
    }
    foreach ($uncheckboxvalue as $uncheck) {
        $bod_update = mysql_query("update bod set status='no' where activityname='" . mysql_real_escape_string($uncheck) . "' and username='$username'", $conn);
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to insert only the value of the current element selected?

Comment: yes madalin only current checkbox value

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this to get the current state o the current checked element:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
var ids = null;//set to null for unchecked
if (this.checked) {//set the value for checked
  var ids =$(this).val();
}
  $.ajax({
    url: "bodcheckbox.php",
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    data: ({
      value: ids,
    }),
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      alert("activitysubmitted");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks madalin if Again the check box is unchecked means i haveto update the status as='no'

Comment: yes on the server side you do a if to test if the value is null or a number and based on that you update your status

Answer (score 0):

You need to check by querying if table has record with same activity and same username. Get the count of result, If it is 0 then Insert the record else no change